# Opening the test on other tab is failing When i run as a test suite

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, ui-automation

I am facing a strange issue in protractor UI test. For one of the test , I have to click on the link and that link opens in different tab.
The test is passing when I run that test alone but It fails when I run it as test suite.

Please check the code and give your suggestions.

```
 function(callback){
            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(tabs){
                var secondTab = tabs[1];
                var firstTab = tabs[0];
                browser.switchTo().window(secondTab).then(function(){
                    expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toBe("www.google.com");
                    element(by.css('heading')).getText().then(function(text){
                        expect(text).toBe('Welcome');
                    });
                    browser.close(); //Close the current Tab
                });
                browser.switchTo().window(firstTab);
                //Log Out from the site
                element(by.id("side-menu")).click();
                element(by.linkText("Logout")).click();
                callback();
            });
        }
```

Comment: what is the error your facing?

Answer (score 0):

if the test pass when you run it as a single test then the issue might  not be related to this piece of code. It might be dependent on how browser is handled in your framework

One thing you can try is give browser.sleep() before and after switching to new tab. Because most of the synchronization issues comes into picture when we run it as suite.